# Why does this canvas animation occasionally scramble itself?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

For a website I am creating, I coded a parallax background using HTML5 `canvas`. Running the snippet below will produce a 192x192 sample of the background animation.

```js
function parallaxCipher(size, color, speed, grid, sector, seed){
  var scr = document.getElementById("parallax" + sector);
  var ctx = scr.getContext("2d");
  ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
  ctx.fillRect(0,0,scr.width,scr.height);
  var xGridMax = Math.ceil(scr.width / grid);
  var yGridMax = Math.ceil(scr.height / grid) + 1;
  var seedList = prng(seed,yGridMax * 2);
  for(var c = 0; c < yGridMax;c++){
    seedList[c] += seedList[c + yGridMax] * 256;
  }
  seedList.length = yGridMax;
  var rotation = Math.floor(Math.floor(Date.now() / speed) / grid) % yGridMax;
  rotation = yGridMax - rotation - 1;
  if(rotation > 0){
    seedList = seedList.slice(seedList.length-rotation).concat(seedList.slice(0,seedList.length - rotation));
  }
  ctx.fillStyle = color;
  for(var a = 0;a<yGridMax;a++){
    var row = prng(seedList[a],Math.ceil((xGridMax + 1)/8));
    var row2 = [];
    for(var d = 0;d<row.length;d++){
      row[d] = row[d].toString(2);
      row[d] = "0".repeat(8 - row[d].length) + row[d];
      row2 = row2.concat(row[d].split(''));
    }
    row2.length = xGridMax + 1;
    var rotation2 = Math.floor(Math.floor(Date.now() / speed) / grid) % xGridMax;
    if(rotation2 > 0){
      row2 = row2.slice(row2.length-rotation2).concat(row2.slice(0,row2.length - rotation2));
    }
    
    for(var b = -1;b<xGridMax;b++){
      ctx.font = size + "px monospace";
      ctx.fillText(row2[b + 1],(b * grid) - (size * 11 / 30) + ((Date.now() / speed) % grid),(a * grid) + (size / 2) - ((Date.now() / speed) % grid));
      
    }
  }
}
function prng(seed, instances){
  //PRNG takes a 16 bit seed
  var primes = [2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47,53,59,61,67,71,73,79,83,89,97,101,103,107,109,113,127,131,137,139,149,151,157,163,167,173,179,181,191,193,197,199,211,223,227,229,233,239,241,251,263,269,271,277,281,283,293,307,311,313,317,331,337,347,349,353,359,367,373,379,383,389,397,401,409,419,421,431,433,439,443,449,457,461,463,467,479,487,491,499,503,509,521,523,541,547,557,563,569,571,577,587,593,599,601,607,613,617,619,631,641,643,647,653,659,661,673,677,683,691,701,709,719,727,733,739,743,751,757,761,769,773,787,797,809,811,821,823,827,829,839,853,857,859,863,877,881,883,887,907,911,919,929,937,941,947,953,967,971,977,983,991,997,1009,1013,1019,1021,1031,1033,1039,1049,1051,1061,1063,1069,1087,1091,1093,1097,1103,1109,1117,1123,1129,1151,1153,1163,1171,1181,1187,1193,1201,1213,1217,1223,1229,1231,1237,1249,1259,1277,1279,1283,1289,1291,1297,1301,1303,1307,1319,1321,1327,1361,1367,1373,1381,1399,1409,1423,1427,1429,1433,1439,1447,1451,1453,1459,1471,1481,1483,1487,1489,1493,1499,1511,1523,1531,1543,1549,1553,1559,1567,1571,1579,1583,1597,1601,1607,1609,1613,1619,1621,1627];
  var res = [];
  var j = seed % 256;
  var k = Math.floor(seed / 256);
  for(var a = 0;a < instances;a++){
    res.push(((primes[j] * primes[k]) % 257) - 1);
    if(primes.includes(res[res.length - 1]) || primes.includes(res[res.length - 1] + 1)){
      j = (j + 1) % 257;
    }else{
      k = (k - 1);
      if(k == -1){
        k = 256;
      }
    }
    if(res[res.length - 1] == undefined){
      console.warn("PRNG error: "  + j + ", " + k + ", " + primes[j] + ", " + primes[k]);
    }
  }
  return res;
}
function animate(){
  window.requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  parallaxCipher(15,"#0f0",25,18,"1",9999);
}
window.requestAnimationFrame(animate);
```

```html
<canvas width="192" height="192" style="border:2px solid black;" id="parallax1">Nope.</canvas>
```

You may notice that every 10 seconds or so, the bits scramble themselves, as if the `seed` value randomly changed, even though the seed in this example is fixed at `9999`.

I think it may be a problem with the `rotation`/`rotation2` values, but I am not entirely sure. In fact, the bug appears to not be in sync with the rotation cycle at all, leaving me at a complete loss as to how this problem is occuring.

Forgive my terrible code, but can anyone help pinpoint the problem? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I tried, but your code is really crazy and I can´t understood it. Your grid is being recreated every cycle, this is not efficient. Try to separate in parts, first generate your random grid, store it in a variable, and put only the animation code in the window.requestAnimationFrame(animate);

Comment: @CharlesCavalcante The PRNG function is actually insanely fast, the animation works perfectly even on my cheap Android phone.

Comment: I know that is fast, but you don´t need to create the grid again every time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I figured it out!**

`rotation2` is supposed to be calculated modulo `xGridMax + 1`, not `xGridMax`.

Thus, the correct animation (large version) is:

```js
function parallaxCipher(size, color, speed, grid, sector, seed){
  var scr = document.getElementById("parallax" + sector);
  var ctx = scr.getContext("2d");
  ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
  ctx.fillRect(0,0,scr.width,scr.height);
  var xGridMax = Math.ceil(scr.width / grid);
  var yGridMax = Math.ceil(scr.height / grid) + 1;
  var seedList = prng(seed,yGridMax * 2);
  for(var c = 0; c < yGridMax;c++){
    seedList[c] += seedList[c + yGridMax] * 256;
  }
  seedList.length = yGridMax;
  var rotation = Math.floor(Math.floor(Date.now() / speed) / grid) % yGridMax;
  rotation = yGridMax - rotation - 1;
  if(rotation > 0){
    seedList = seedList.slice(seedList.length-rotation).concat(seedList.slice(0,seedList.length - rotation));
  }
  ctx.fillStyle = color;
  for(var a = 0;a<yGridMax;a++){
    var row = prng(seedList[a],Math.ceil((xGridMax + 1)/8));
    var row2 = [];
    for(var d = 0;d<row.length;d++){
      row[d] = row[d].toString(2);
      row[d] = "0".repeat(8 - row[d].length) + row[d];
      row2 = row2.concat(row[d].split(''));
    }
    row2.length = xGridMax + 1;
    var rotation2 = Math.floor(Math.floor(Date.now() / speed) / grid) % (xGridMax+1);
    if(rotation2 > 0){
      row2 = row2.slice(row2.length-rotation2).concat(row2.slice(0,row2.length - rotation2));
    }
    
    for(var b = -1;b<xGridMax;b++){
      ctx.font = size + "px monospace";
      ctx.fillText(row2[b + 1],(b * grid) - (size * 11 / 30) + ((Date.now() / speed) % grid),(a * grid) + (size / 2) - ((Date.now() / speed) % grid));
      
    }
  }
}
function prng(seed, instances){
  //PRNG takes a 16 bit seed
  var primes = [2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47,53,59,61,67,71,73,79,83,89,97,101,103,107,109,113,127,131,137,139,149,151,157,163,167,173,179,181,191,193,197,199,211,223,227,229,233,239,241,251,263,269,271,277,281,283,293,307,311,313,317,331,337,347,349,353,359,367,373,379,383,389,397,401,409,419,421,431,433,439,443,449,457,461,463,467,479,487,491,499,503,509,521,523,541,547,557,563,569,571,577,587,593,599,601,607,613,617,619,631,641,643,647,653,659,661,673,677,683,691,701,709,719,727,733,739,743,751,757,761,769,773,787,797,809,811,821,823,827,829,839,853,857,859,863,877,881,883,887,907,911,919,929,937,941,947,953,967,971,977,983,991,997,1009,1013,1019,1021,1031,1033,1039,1049,1051,1061,1063,1069,1087,1091,1093,1097,1103,1109,1117,1123,1129,1151,1153,1163,1171,1181,1187,1193,1201,1213,1217,1223,1229,1231,1237,1249,1259,1277,1279,1283,1289,1291,1297,1301,1303,1307,1319,1321,1327,1361,1367,1373,1381,1399,1409,1423,1427,1429,1433,1439,1447,1451,1453,1459,1471,1481,1483,1487,1489,1493,1499,1511,1523,1531,1543,1549,1553,1559,1567,1571,1579,1583,1597,1601,1607,1609,1613,1619,1621,1627];
  var res = [];
  var j = seed % 256;
  var k = Math.floor(seed / 256);
  for(var a = 0;a < instances;a++){
    res.push(((primes[j] * primes[k]) % 257) - 1);
    if(primes.includes(res[res.length - 1]) || primes.includes(res[res.length - 1] + 1)){
      j = (j + 1) % 257;
    }else{
      k = (k - 1);
      if(k == -1){
        k = 256;
      }
    }
    if(res[res.length - 1] == undefined){
      console.warn("PRNG error: "  + j + ", " + k + ", " + primes[j] + ", " + primes[k]);
    }
  }
  return res;
}
function animate(){
  window.requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  parallaxCipher(15,"#0f0",25,18,"1",9999);
}
window.requestAnimationFrame(animate);
```

```html
<canvas width="512" height="512" style="border:2px solid black;" id="parallax1">Nope.</canvas>
```